# Adding background image to button using CSS

Tags: html, css, button

I am trying to add a background image to a button (or link with the same class) which already has a background color.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BNvke/

The button looks great by itself, but I am trying to make it so that if I add a certain class, the padding will be adjusted and a background image will be displayed, however the image does not show. Here is the CSS/HTML:

```css
.button {
    padding: 10px; 
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, FreeSans, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 1em;
    position: relative;
    outline: none;
    overflow: visible;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px; 
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0 #CCCCCC;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0 #CCCCCC;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0 #CCCCCC;
}

.button_blue {
    border: 1px solid #305875;
    color: #FBFBFB;
    background-color: #3D6E97;
}

.button_blue:hover {
    color: #FBFBFB;
    opacity: 0.9; 
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);        
}

.button_about { 
    background-image: url(http://i47.tinypic.com/2ni0ahd.png) 3px 5px no-repeat;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}​
```

```html
<p><a class="button button_blue">Without Background</a></p>

<p><a class="button button_blue button_about">With Background</a></p>​
```

How can I get that background image to show?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

see http://jsfiddle.net/BNvke/1/

just change

```
background-image url(http://i47.tinypic.com/2ni0ahd.png) 3px 5px no-repeat;
```

with

```
background: url(http://i47.tinypic.com/2ni0ahd.png) 3px 5px no-repeat;
```

and move up the last rule so the rule about `background-color` defined for `.button_blue` can be applied on cascade

Answer (score 0):

```
.button {
    background: url(http://i47.tinypic.com/2ni0ahd.png);
    background-repeat: 3px 5px no-repeat;
}
```